# By.XPATH problem in an automatic click with Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I would like to automatically click on the blue logo of the likes (the one with the thumb inside), in order to open the list of those who have left the likes. I am referring to this little blue logo:

[image]

In the question I want to focus only on this small request, on this small click. I think I am doing it right, but surely there is something wrong. I used `By.XPATH`., More precisely: `//*[@id="jsc_c_z"]/span[1]/span/span/div`

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="jsc_c_z"]/span[1]/span/span/div'))).click()
```

NOTA :I've noticed that the IDs and ranges on this page look suspiciously obfuscated and so maybe they won't necessarily be the same every time. So maybe I don't think id = "jsc_c_z" that will be reliable. You may need to resort to using aria-labeld of the attribute on the target element div.

This instead is the link I would like to open https://www.facebook.com/FranzKafkaAuthor/posts/3985338151528881.

IMPORTANT: You have to enter with the Facebook login, but who does not want to do so will post a screenshot
[image]

I hope someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: Is there someone who can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself. The solution was:

```
 WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='j1lvzwm4']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try the Xpath like this,

```
//*[@id="jsc_c_z"]/span[3]/div/img
```

as the image tag has the link and not the div tag
If it does not work, try adding the arial label while locating the div.

Comment: Your code doesn't work. Can you review it please? Can you add the arial label? Thanks

Comment: Try This, `//span[@id="jsc_c_z"]/span[3]/div[@aria-label='Mi Piace: 656 persone']/img`

Answer (score 0):

the ids and spans in this page look suspiciously obfuscated, and thus won't necessarily be the same every time.  I don't think the `id="jsc_c_z"` will be reliable.  you may need to resort to using the `aria-label` attribute on the target `div` element.  I can't test this, but the xpath would be something along the lines of;

```
//div[starts-with(@aria-label,'Mi piace:')]
```

and of course, you'd need to change that text if you are running this for users with different languages.

Comment: Can you show me the code in your answer? I didn't understand what you say. I'm just starting out in Python. If the answer is correct, I will of course vote and accept your question. Thanks

Comment: @Jas_99 I've thrown in an xpath that may work.  I can't test it though, so no guarantee. :-)

Comment: I just tried it. Does not work. Thanks. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: what sort of error message do you get?

Comment: I'm not getting any error messages. No error message. There is simply no click on that blue like logo.

Comment: Sure, run your code in an IDE with a debugger and set a breakpoint at the spot where you make this call to WebDriverWait.  then play around with the xpath.  perhaps there's a typo?  perhaps we need double quotes not single quotes?  try finding other elements at the same time that you know the xpath for to confirm that it's in the same place... oh, is this thing sitting inside an iframe?  that could be the problem.